# Groovy: Date and Time comparisons with a slight delay

Tags: datetime, groovy

So I have the following script:

```
import groovy.time.TimeCategory

def dueDate = context.expand( '${Test 4 - create user task#Response#$[\'_embedded\'][\'userTaskDtoList\'][0][\'dueDate\']}' )

def date = new Date(messageExchange.getTimestamp())

use(groovy.time.TimeCategory){
    after24Hours = (date + 24.hours).format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC')) }

assert dueDate == after24Hours
```

What I'm trying to do with this is take the date and time from a REST request (dueDate - which comes in UTC format and with a 24h delay) and create a new date and time from the timestamp of the moment when that request has been sent, which is registered from my system. I then convert that time to UTC to accommodate the format from dueDate and add 24h to it. At the end I verify that the date and time from dueDate and after24Hours is the same.

The output does return the same time but in certain cases if there is a delay between the time the request is being sent and the time is received then the assertion will fail. This depends on the server, usually there is a difference of like 1 millisecond but I'm thinking that if the server will be slower at some point this will definitely be bigger.

What could I do to allow some margin of error in the assertion, maybe like a few seconds or even a couple of minutes?

Ok, so I managed to do this:

```
import groovy.time.*

def dueDate = context.expand( '${Test 4 - create user task#Response#$[\'_embedded\'][\'userTaskDtoList\'][0][\'dueDate\']}' )
def date = new Date(messageExchange.getTimestamp())

use(groovy.time.TimeCategory){
    after24Hours = (date + 24.hours).format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC'))
     def date1 = Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", dueDate)
     def date2 = Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", after24Hours)
     TimeDuration difference = TimeCategory.minus(date2, date1) 
     log.info date1
     log.info date2
     assert difference < 2.minutes
     }
```

The script seems to work and it does return an error only if the time is longer than the one I've set in the assertion.
Unfortunately I have another issue now.
For some reason, my date output looks like this:

```
Fri Oct 01 16:24:10 EEST 2021: INFO: Sat Oct 02 13:24:10 EEST 2021
```

Which is not the correct format. That date should appear in the Zulu format, after all when I parsed the dates that was the format that I used.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

> What could I do to allow some margin of error in the assertion, maybe
> like a few seconds or even a couple of minutes?

Instead of asserting that they are equal, you could assert that the difference between them is less than a threshold that you get to define.

Comment: So I've found the http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/time/Duration.html and I've tried to get a difference between the times like this 
TimeDuration difference = TimeCategory.minus(after24Hours, dueDate)
But I receive the following error: 
Error in assertion script No signature of method: static groovy.time.TimeCategory.minus() is applicable for argument types: (String, String)
Do I have to maybe parse the dates, somehow?

Answer (score 2):

If you use something like [AssertJ](https://assertj.github.io/doc/), and I'd recommend you do, then you can do something like the following:

```
assertThat(dueDate).isCloseTo(after24Hours, within(1, ChronoUnit.MINUTE));
```

This will give a small margin to the comparison of the dates, and should fix your issue.

Comment: This looks pretty good. I read a bit about it from the link that you sent and I wish that I could use it but I'm not the only one who is supposed to run these tests and from what I can tell this would require everyone to use that library? Thanks though, this looks great

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with that everyone must use it. You don't have to replace your current asserts, it's just an extra option you can give to your colleagues. Maybe try it out first. There's also other frameworks, like Google Truth, which does a similar thing.